# Can someone explain how a dictionary can hold different input values under one key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this simple looping code that takes in a line of user input and (after making this into a list) puts the individual words into a dictionary as keys, with the lineCount number being the value. Can someone explain how to adjust this so that if the same word is entered on a different line, it doesn't replace the dictionary value but instead just adds to it?

```
import string
lineCount = 1
q = raw_input("enter something")
d = {}

while q != "no":
    q = q.split()
    for word in q:
        d[word] = lineCount
    lineCount += 1
    q = raw_input("enter something")

print d
```

For example, if the input is "x y" on line 1, and "x n" on line 2, the dictionary should print as "x: 1,2 y:1 n:2" but currently it would only print "x:2 y:1 n:2" as the original lineCount value associated with key x is replaced. If possible, please avoid importing collections in the solution, as I would rather understand the longest way possible first.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you do not use list to store your values? for example `'x': [1, 2]`

Comment: A list would work, but as I want this code to be able to handle longer sentences on each line I think a dictionary solution is much more appropriate. The x and y thing was really just an example

Comment: It's still a dictionary, but the *values* in the dictionary are lists of line numbers.

Comment: @user7222454 I do not mean to replace your dictionary with a list, just the values of your dictionary items to be like this `{'x': [1, 2], 'y': [1]}`

Comment: Oh right, I understand. So what would a piece of sample code look like?

Comment: @user7222454 Take a look at my solution below, I believe it is better than concatenating line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lists for your dictionary values, you can have the following solution:

```
line_count = 1
q = raw_input("enter something: ")
d = {}

while q != "no":
    words = q.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in d and line_count not in d[word]:
            d[word].append(line_count)
        else:
            d[word] = [line_count]
    line_count += 1
    q = raw_input("enter something: ")

print d
```

**Example of output:**

```
>>> python word_lines.py
enter something: hello world
enter something: hello
enter something: world
enter something: sof
enter something: no
{'world': [1, 3], 'hello': [1, 2], 'sof': [4]}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: I do have one quick follow up, if it isn't too much bother; what adjustments would need to be made for handling the same word on one line? i.e. if input is "hello hello world" on line 1, and "world" on line 2, instead of the values being printed as {'hello': [1,1,2], 'world':[2]} it just prints {'hello': [1,2], 'world':[2]}.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to add that in your condition like this: `if word in d and line_count not in d[word]`, take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: you can also use a set that automatically remove duplicates

Comment: @ettanany Thanks so much, this helps me to understand a lot more

Answer (score 1):

You can use get if a default value like in the code below:

```
lineCount = 1
q = raw_input("enter something")
d = {}

while q != "no":
    q = q.split()
    for word in q:
        d[word] = d.get(word, 0) + 1
    lineCount += 1
    query = raw_input("enter something")
```

When you add the word for the first time, the get won't find the word and will return 0 (the default value). So you add this with 1 to update the result.

Comment: I have just run this and it gives me the same problem that x is only associated with its most recent value if input twice

Comment: Change the line inside the loop to this: `d[word] = d.get(word, []) + [lineCount]` and the value at each key will be the list of lines that it was in.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a Dictionary instead of a list as suggested by ettanany, I would suggest you use the lines as the keys and the words as values since lines are unique and words are not. I'm sure you can figure this out without a code sample :)